# Validating an Array with least number of numeric Characters

Tags: java

I have an array of strings:

```
void populateStringArray()
{
toppings = new String[20];

toppings[0] = "Cheese12";
toppings[1] = "Pepperoni1234";
toppings[2] = "Black Olives1";
// ...
```

And I want to return the one with least numeric characters.

Can some one suggest the logic to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? I would create a string variable for holding the one with least numerics so far, and an int variable for holding the number, loop through the array, and count the number of numerics using a regex, replacing the held one if the one you are checking has less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over characters and use [`Character.isDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) to count digits in the string.

```
   String str = "Cheese12";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

If using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is an Option, you can just do this:

```
int digitChars = CharMatcher.DIGIT.countIn(yourString)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of digits in a string `str` with

```
str.length() - str.replaceAll("\\d", "").length()
```

Simple as pie.

Now all you have to do is loop over your array `toppings` and find the string `s` for which `str.length() - str.replaceAll("\\d", "").length()` is least.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); //regex pattern to find integers on a string
int index = 0;
int test;
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i : toppings.size()-1){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(toppings[i]);
    if (m.find()) { //assuming only one number to find
      test = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
      if (test < lowest){
          lowest = test;
          index = i;
      }
    }
}
return patterns[index]; //in case of tie the lowest index wins
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String leastChar(){

        int leastChar=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String leastTopping=null;

        int eachToppingTemp=0;

        for (String topping:toppings){

            if (topping==null) continue;


            eachToppingTemp= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (char eachChar:topping.toCharArray()){
                if (Character.isDigit(eachChar)){
                    eachToppingTemp++;
                }
            }

            if (eachToppingTemp<leastChar){
                leastChar=eachToppingTemp;
                leastTopping=topping;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Lowest char topping : "+leastTopping);
        return leastTopping;
}
```

Comment: Read one more time the question and rethink your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the O(n*m) here?

Comment: That depend on data you are working, if only alphanumeric you could sort the string and array so you would have O(n log n * m log m).

Answer (score 0):

You can find all digits in your string using regex and count the number of digits:

```
public int getNumberOfDigitsInString(String input) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
  int count = 0;
  while (matcher.find()) 
    count += matcher.group().length();
  return count;
}
```

Now you can just iterate over your array and find the one with the least amount of digits:

```
int lowestN = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
String finalString = "";
for (String str:toppings) {
  int currentN = getNumberOfDigitsInString(str);
  if (lowestN > currentN) {
    finalStr = str;
    lowestN = currentN;
  }
}
System.out.println("Result: " + finalStr + " (has " + lowestN + " digits in it)");
```